# HttpClient postAsync with xml body ends with BadRequest error

Tags: c#, xml, dotnet-httpclient

I want to post the xml string message to server but it is ending up with the bad request.
Seems to be a very simple but not getting what miskake I am doing?

please help. :(

***msgXML is a stringified xml***

```
 public static async Task<string> SendMessageAsync(string msgXml)
 {
  using (CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource())
  {
    CancellationToken cancellation = source.Token;
    HttpClient client = HttpClientProvider.GetInstance;
    //client.BaseAddress = new Uri(myUri);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-HTTP-Dest-Address", destinationAddress);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/xml;charset=utf-8");
    var httpContent = new StringContent(msgXml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(myUri, httpContent, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
       throw new Exception("Invalid URI");
     }
  }
}
```

My msgXML:

```
<MSG>
 <HeaderCommon>
  other elements....
  <payload></payload>
 </HeaderCommon>
</MSG>
```

The error i am getting is only:

```
    ReasonPhrase: "Bad Request"
    statusCode: 400
```

The server is not secure(http).

Comment: please amend your post to show the xml and the full exception message

Comment: @JohnB Updated the question, I am getting 400 badrequest only.

Comment: Well, what uri are you posting to?  Its commented out.  You'd have to ask whoever owns that uri.

Comment: It could be bad because: they require a client cert, they require basic auth, you say your message is soap/xml and it is not soap, you have two different headers identifying what kind of message it is, they don't accept xml posts, etc

Comment: @BrianWhite instead of adding the uri to BaseAddress, I have directly added the uri to client.PostAsync(myUri, httpContent, cancellationToken).

Comment: You have a SOAP and it looks like you are doing a request without validation.  If the server is secure (https) than it is returning a bad request because you didn't sign the request and sever wants a signed request.

Comment: I tried with certificate as well:
and My mistake i am not posting the soap. so removed "Content-Type" "Soap" from above asked question.

     WebRequestHandler requestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
      requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert1);
      HttpClient client = HttpClientProvider.GetSecureInstance(requestHandler);

Comment: Was asking about myUri because you just use it without defining it or passing it in :)      I'm sure you have it set in real code, but i can only see this

Comment: @BrianWhite okay, I have defined myuri in my code and it is http://(not secure) :)